# Xamarin forms: string binding isn't updating in. the view when property is set inside a timer method. why no work?

Tags: c#, xamarin, xamarin.forms, mvvm

Trying to constantly update a string in a view. using MVVM so have set up my view model and set up a timer to constantly update the string with the current time.

timer is in the constructor of the view model and the constructor is called in the constructor of the code-behind for the view.

for some reason any time i set the string property within the method in the timer it doesn't update the view? I have a console write line within the timer method that works as expected. Why isn't the  view getting the updated string ?

View Model

```
public class MainViewModel
    {

        //
        TimeIntervals Interval = TimeIntervals.Seconds;

        int DurationOfInterval = 1;

        

        public MainViewModel()
        {
            
            TimeLeft = "2023.5.18";

            DateTime LastRecordedTime = DateTime.MinValue;

            Device.StartTimer(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(3), () =>
            { 

                
                DateTime CurrentTime = DateTime.Now;

                Console.WriteLine($"time has passed {LastRecordedTime.ToString("dd/MM/yyyy |HH:mm:ss")}");

                       
                TimeLeft = CurrentTime.ToString();

                return true;



            });

        }

        string timeLeft;

        public string TimeLeft
        {
            set { SetProperty(ref timeLeft, value); }
            get { return timeLeft; }
        }
       
        bool SetProperty<T>(ref T storage, T value, [CallerMemberName] string PropertyName = null)
        {
            if (Object.Equals(storage, value))
                return false;
            storage = value;
            OnPropertyChanged(PropertyName);
            return true;
        }

        public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
        protected void OnPropertyChanged([CallerMemberName] string PropertyName = null)
        {
            PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(PropertyName));
        }
```

View

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<ContentPage xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
             xmlns:local="clr-namespace:DeathClock.Main"
             x:Class="DeathClock.MainPage">

    <ContentPage.BindingContext>
        <local:MainViewModel/>

    </ContentPage.BindingContext>

    <StackLayout Background="black">
        <Grid ColumnDefinitions="3*,1*" BackgroundColor="Black" >
            <Grid Grid.Column="0" RowDefinitions = "2*,400,1*"  Padding="5" >
                <Grid Grid.Column="0" ColumnDefinitions="50,200" >
                    <Button Grid.Column="0" Text="Config" Command="{Binding goToSettings}"/>

                </Grid>
            
                <Grid  Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="0" RowDefinitions="2*,2*" ColumnDefinitions="2*,2*,2*"  Padding="5">
                    <Label Grid.Column="0" Grid.Row="0" VerticalOptions="CenterAndExpand" FontSize="Title" Text="{Binding TimeSpent}" BackgroundColor="Purple"/>
                    <Label Grid.Column="0" Grid.Row="1" VerticalOptions="CenterAndExpand" FontSize="Title" Text="{Binding TimeLeft}" BackgroundColor="Purple"/>

                
                </Grid>
                
            



            </Grid>
            <StackLayout Grid.Column="1" Rotation="-90" VerticalOptions="CenterAndExpand" HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand" ScaleX="5" Background="black" >
                    
                    <ProgressBar ProgressColor="Bisque" Progress="{Binding LifeProgress}" VerticalOptions="FillAndExpand" HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand" ScaleY="20" ></ProgressBar>

            </StackLayout>
        </Grid>
    </StackLayout>

</ContentPage>
```

Code Behind

```
public partial class MainPage : ContentPage
    {
       

       
        public MainPage()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            MainViewModel ViewModel = new MainViewModel();



        }

        
      
    }
```

Comment: first, please edit your code when posting.  There is a HUGE amount of unneeded whitespace.  Second, your `MainViewModel` class does not implement `INotifyPropertyChanged`.  Third, you are setting your VM in both XAML and code.  Pick one or the other.

Comment: @Jason Yeah that sorted it thanks god i feel stupid for not seeing that. still interesting how the view updated outside the timer without implementing INotifyPropertyChanged. Sorry that the amount of white space caused you so much strife. i will do better next time

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> still interesting how the view updated outside the timer without
> implementing INotifyPropertyChanged.

For this, you also need to implement interface `INotifyPropertyChanged` for your view model.

From official document [ViewModels and Property-Change Notifications](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/app-fundamentals/data-binding/binding-mode#viewmodels-and-property-change-notifications),we could find that:

> The ViewModel is the data-binding source. The ViewModel does not
> define bindable properties, but it does implement a notification
> mechanism that allows the binding infrastructure to be notified when
> the value of a property changes. This notification mechanism is the
> INotifyPropertyChanged interface, which defines a single event named
> PropertyChanged. A class that implements this interface generally
> fires the event when one of its public properties changes value.

So, you need to implement interface `INotifyPropertyChanged` and call function `OnPropertyChanged` for the properties that you want to update the UI automatically while changing the value of these properties.

For example:

```
        public string TimeLeft
    {
        set { SetProperty(ref timeLeft, value); }
        get { return timeLeft; }
    }

    string timeSpent;
    public string TimeSpent
    {
        set { SetProperty(ref timeSpent, value); }
        get { return timeSpent; }
    }
```

Besides,you can change the value of the property at any time according to your needs, and as long as you implement interface `INotifyPropertyChanged` for your view model and call `OnPropertyChanged` for your property, the UI will be automatically updated.

Based on your code,I added a command to the viewmodel and bind to the button to change the value of property `TimeLeft` and `TimeSpent`,then the UI will update itself.

```
  public ICommand UpdateCommand { get; set; }

  UpdateCommand = new Command(updateTimeMethod);
```

method `updateTimeMethod`

```
private void updateTimeMethod(object obj)
{
    TimeLeft = "2023.5.21";

    TimeSpent = "TimeSpent 2";
}
```

You can refer to the whole code here:

```
public class MainViewModel: INotifyPropertyChanged 
{
   // TimeIntervals Interval = TimeIntervals.Seconds;

    int DurationOfInterval = 1;

    public ICommand UpdateCommand { get; set; }

    public MainViewModel()
    {

        TimeLeft = "2023.5.18";

        TimeSpent = "TimeSpent 1";

        DateTime LastRecordedTime = DateTime.MinValue;

        Device.StartTimer(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(3), () =>
        {
            DateTime CurrentTime = DateTime.Now;

            Console.WriteLine($"time has passed {LastRecordedTime.ToString("dd/MM/yyyy |HH:mm:ss")}");


            TimeLeft = CurrentTime.ToString();

            return true;
        });

        UpdateCommand = new Command(updateTimeMethod);
    }

    private void updateTimeMethod(object obj)
    {
        TimeLeft = "2023.5.21";

        TimeSpent = "TimeSpent 2";
    }

    string timeLeft;

    public string TimeLeft
    {
        set { SetProperty(ref timeLeft, value); }
        get { return timeLeft; }
    }

    string timeSpent;
    public string TimeSpent
    {
        set { SetProperty(ref timeSpent, value); }
        get { return timeSpent; }
    }

    bool SetProperty<T>(ref T storage, T value, [CallerMemberName] string PropertyName = null)
    {
        if (Object.Equals(storage, value))
            return false;
        storage = value;
        OnPropertyChanged(PropertyName);
        return true;
    }

    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
    protected void OnPropertyChanged([CallerMemberName] string PropertyName = null)
    {
        PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(PropertyName));
    }
}
```

**MainPage.xaml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?> 
<ContentPage xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml" 
             xmlns:mvvmapp521="clr-namespace:MvvMApp521"
             x:Class="MvvMApp521.MainPage">

    <ContentPage.BindingContext>
        <mvvmapp521:MainViewModel/>
    </ContentPage.BindingContext>

    <StackLayout Background="black">
        <Label  VerticalOptions="CenterAndExpand" FontSize="Title" Text="{Binding TimeSpent}" BackgroundColor="Purple"/>
        <Label  VerticalOptions="CenterAndExpand" FontSize="Title" Text="{Binding TimeLeft}" BackgroundColor="Purple"/>

        <Button   Text="reset value" HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand" HeightRequest="50"    Command="{Binding UpdateCommand}"/>
    </StackLayout>

</ContentPage>
```

Note:

Since you have set the `MainViewModel` for the page on `Yourpage.xaml`, you don't need to set it again on the `Yourpage.xaml.cs`, so please remove the code :

```
public partial class MainPage : ContentPage
{             
    public MainPage()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        // comment out the following code here
        // MainViewModel ViewModel = new MainViewModel();
    }   
}
```